# Android target: not installed e erro geral cordova

Tags: apache-cordova

Quando eu rodo o comando

```
cordova requirements
```

o terminal me retorna:

```
Android Studio project detected

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed 
spawn EACCES
Gradle: installed /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle
(node:26241) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Some of requirements check failed
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js:414:27
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
(node:26241) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:26241) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Eu tenho as APIs do SDK manager instaladas, mas nenhuma aparece e a pasta onde estas APIs estão instaladas ja esta no PATH do sistema. Já não sei mais como resolver.